# Hide Particular Columns In Power BI (using Analysis Services 'Connect-Live' Option)

Tags: powerbi

How can I hide a particular column in Power BI when I am using SQL Server Analysis Services 'Connect-Live' option?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, that needs to be handled in the source cube (whether it be MD or TAB). This seems to be by design.